# relation between 4 tables laravel

Tags: php, laravel, relational-database

I have 4 tables

**Packages:**

```
id
name
```

**Tests:**

```
id
name
subcategory_id
```

**category:**

```
id
name
parent_id = 0 // if main category
```

**packages_tests:(pivotTable)**

```
id
package_id
test_id
```

I want to get tests inside each package with category like that

```
packages: [
   name: package1
   categories: [
     {
       name: mainCategory1
       tests: [
         {test1},
         {test2}
       ]
     },
     {
       name: mainCategory2
       tests: [
         {test3},
         {test4}
       ]
     }
   ]
]
```

I made some relationships between models but I can't achieve this shape of code.

Comment: There is no relevant ID in the `category` table.

Comment: @SahilGupta `Category` plays two roles it's main category and sub category i made self relationship with parent_id

Comment: Can you share the relationships you achieved so far?

Comment: okay, @shw2y. Please check my solution. Hope it will help

Comment: @ChristopheHubert my relationships gave me this code but i think i need reversed it
              `{
                    "id": 1,
                    "nameEn": "test1",
                    "category_id": 2,
                  
                    "sub_category": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "nameEn": "SubCat1",
                        "parent_id": 1,
                        "main_categories": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "nameEn": "Laboratory",
                        }
                    }
                }
`

Answer (score 0):

I'm expecting the `Tests` table has `category_id`.

Make models like [(Read more about Laravel relations)](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships):-

Package.php

```
public function packageTests()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PackagesTests::class)
}
```

PackageTest.php

```
public function tests()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Test::class)
}
```

Test.php

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Category::class)
}
```

I don't have an idea about mappings (one-one, one-many). I guess them, hope they are right.

Now access them like.

```
Package::with('packageTests')
        ->with('packageTests.tests')
        ->with('packageTests.tests.category')
        ->where('condition_array')
        ->get()
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts bur packages_tests just pivotTable for (packages and tests) then there is relation between tests and subCategory using category_id from category table and there is another relation between sub category and main category using parent_id from category table